# Stretch Bitmap in TImageControl

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a TImageControl in top of my form.it may have image with different sizes.
How to stretch a bitmap in TImageControl in XE5?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `TImage` instead of a `TImageControl` for that, loading the source image into the `MultiResBitmap` property. 
Also, if you don't want to suffer with creating multiple images at different resolutions, just load the image onto it and change the `TImage's WrapMode` property to `iwStretch`.

Comment: Anytime. Just a tip, always post the tag Delphi (not only delphi-XE5). Your post will have more visibility that way.